# Calling a function from angular ng-repeat

Tags: node.js, angularjs, api, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have recently started re-writing an existing piece of PHP code in AngularJS and NodeJS. In short, the code fetches all staff members from an api call, then it loops each of these staff members and makes another api call to fetch all appointments relevant to that staff member.

The back-end API (written in node and express) is working perfectly. I have made manual checks to each path and it has returned the correct JSON data from the MySQL DB.

Here is my Angular application code for the controller:

```
var calendar = angular.module('calendar', []);

function mainController($scope, $http) {

//Get staff
$http.get('/api/staff')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.staff = data;
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    }); 


    $scope.getApps = function($staff) {
        $http.get('/api/' + $staff + '/appointments')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.appointments = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + data);
            }); 


    } 

}
```

My index.html:

```
<html ng-app="calendar">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!-- Optimize mobile viewport -->

<title>Calendar</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
<script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="mainController">

<div class="staff_Col" ng-repeat="s in staff">

    <div class="staff_Header">  
        {{ s.FirstName }}
    </div>     

    {{ getApps(s.StaffID) }}

.......     

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

When the page loads it calls all staff members then uses the ng-repeat to loop, and using the staffid it then calls the getApps function.

The problem i'm having is that everytime i load the page it ends up killing my browser. From what i can observe in the console, it makes the initial call for every staff member, then it loops back through them again, until it freezes and seizes the browser.

I feel as if this is a gap in my knowledge from PHP to Angular and would greatly appreciate some guidance. Thanks for any help guys and girls!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime $digest process will be called it will execute `getApps` function it won't be forced only on `staff` change, $http returns promises and that can be nicely utilised for your purposes. In the following update to your code staff.appointments will be created and then reflected in view once the request is resolved, you don't need to call a function from view unless you want to update, but that should use a method designed for it

#### js

```
$http.get('/api/staff')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.staff = data;
        angular.forEach($scope.staff, function (staff) {
          $http.get('/api/' + staff.StaffID + '/appointments').then(function(response){
            staff.appointments = response.data
          })
        })
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
```

#### html

```
<div class="staff_Col" ng-repeat="s in staff">

    <div class="staff_Header">  
        {{ s.FirstName }}
    </div>     

    {{ s.appointments }}

.......     

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Moving away from PHP is being very awkward. The potential of this language is incredible, i just need to get my head around how data is bound and served. Thanks again!

Comment: no problem, jump to #angularjs irc on irc.freenode.org if you are looking for help

Answer (score 0):

You make an api request for each member, every time when something in $scope.staff changes. Then after each request you rewrite value of $scope.appointments - that one is weird.

Any way try avoiding too much api requests. For example you can make an api which receives an array of IDs and return all data at once. And don't do it inside repeat, or at least use $http cache:true.

Comment: I know i could use a multi-dimensional array with all data (i avoided it because the query is massively complex). I'm curious as to why, if there is 4 staff members and ng-repeat loops through 4 times, how it can get stuck in an infinite loop of calls that seizes the browser.